# Observing other ViewModels from a ViewModel

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm working on a POS type app and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle showing the total of the items the user has selected. For simplicity's sake, assume the user can either select an item or de-select it (they can't have multiples of an item). This is what I was considering but I'm not sure if it's the right way:

*Model*

```
public class Item {
    public String name;
    public double cost;
}
```

*Item ViewModel*

```
public class ItemViewModel {
    private Item model;
    private MutableLiveData<Boolean> isSelected;

    public ItemViewModel(Item model){
        this.model = model;
        this.isSelected = new MutableLiveData<>(false);
    }

    //...isSelected getter and code to handle selection...//
}
```

*Main ViewModel*

```
public class MainViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<List<ItemViewModel>> items;
    private final MutableLiveData<Double> totalCost;

    public MainViewModel(List<Item> items){
        List<ItemViewModel> viewModels = new ArrayList<>();

        for(Item item : items) {
            ItemViewModel vm = new ItemViewModel(item);
            vm.getIsSelected().observerForever(this::onSelectionChanged);
            viewModels.add(vm);
        }

        this.items = new MutableLiveData<>(viewModels);
        this.totalCost = new MutableLiveData<>(0.00d);
    }   

    private void onSelectionChanged(Boolean value){
        double total = 0.00d;
        //...total all selected items...//
        this.totalCost.postValue(total);
    }
}
```

Specifically is it alright to observer another ViewModel? Am I risking memory leaks by doing this? Is this the wrong way to approach this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's anything fundamentally "wrong" with a VM observing another VM.  But I suggest taking a good look at this line of code:

```
vm.getIsSelected().observerForever(this::onSelectionChanged);
```

`observeForever` is probably not what you want to do, as it doesn't respect the VM's lifecycle.  An Android VM [has a lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) (read those docs carefully) that's matched by the component (android/fragment) that's using it, and this VM is going to keep receiving updates after that component is destroyed.  That sounds leaky to me.

It's probably better for the VM to expose the inner VMs directly to the activity/fragment to consume directly, according to their own lifecycles.

Your VM should also subclass [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel).